# beamer: Spacing Between Frame Title and Content Varies With Content (even using the t option)

Tags: beamer, spacing

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{-1.0ex}}{\vspace*{-1.0ex}}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=3mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=3mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame Title}
\color{blue}\vrule width\textwidth height\textwidth
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame Title}
Text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame Title}
\color{blue}\vrule width\textwidth height\textwidth
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Frame Title}
\begin{block}{Block Title}
Block Text.
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> I want to have a **constant vertical spacing** **between** the **frame title and**
>   the **top line** of the "arbitrary" **content** (text, block, ...). The reason is, that I do not like the
>   "dancing" when I go to the next slide.

Comment: I hope your colour scheme will change in the final document ;-) I assume that the `block` environment has some additional top spacing. And your colour '\vrule' is of course too large vertically

Comment: You will see the same behaviour for list etc. These environments just add a bit of space at their top.

Comment: @samcarter Ok - thanks. So this is more or less the way it is then I guess.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You can always move the block manually.